# In pandas dataframe, given two list columns, access the values of first column on the basis of the values in second column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have Pandas data frame with two list columns:

```
   df = 
           a                          label
        [1, 2, 4, 5]                    [0, 0, 1, 0]
        [100, 12, 23, 4]                [1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Ultimately, I want to form a new column `a_positive`, which is also a list containing all the elements of `a` for which `label` is `1`, so:

```
 df_output =
         a                                  label                a_positive            
        [1, 2, 4, 5]                    [0, 0, 1, 0]              [4]
        [100, 12, 23, 4]                [1, 0, 0, 1]              [100, 4]
```

Is it possible to do so using `apply` and `zip` ing the lists together??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try list comprehension

```
df['a_positive'] = [[a[i] for i,x in enumerate(b) if x] for a, b in zip(df.a, df.label)]

Out[440]:
                  a         label a_positive
0      [1, 2, 4, 5]  [0, 0, 1, 0]        [4]
1  [100, 12, 23, 4]  [1, 0, 0, 1]   [100, 4]
```

Comment: Your solution was fastest.

Comment: Yeah, list comprehension is usually the fastest when working with dataframe of strings and list.

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
df['new']=df.apply( lambda x : [s  for s, t in zip(x['a'],x['label']) if t==1],axis=1)
df
Out[78]: 
                  a         label       new
0      [1, 2, 4, 5]  [0, 0, 1, 0]       [4]
1  [100, 12, 23, 4]  [1, 0, 0, 1]  [100, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `assign`

```py
print(df.assign(a_positive=lambda x: [[df['a'][key][idx] for idx in [c for c, val in enumerate(array) if val == 1]] for key, array in enumerate(df['label'])]))
```

Output:

```
                  a         label a_positive
0      [1, 2, 4, 5]  [0, 0, 1, 0]        [4]
1  [100, 12, 23, 4]  [1, 0, 0, 1]   [100, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import numpy as np

df['a'] = df['a'].apply(np.array)
df['a_positive'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.a[list(map(bool, x.label))],axis=1)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                  a         label a_positive
0      [1, 2, 4, 5]  [0, 0, 1, 0]        [4]
1  [100, 12, 23, 4]  [1, 0, 0, 1]   [100, 4]
```